# iOS7 sending SMS from inside the app has a misaligned modal view

Tags: objective-c, ios7, sms, message

I'm writing an app where I need to allow the user sending SMS from within the app.

It works fine on iOS6 but not on iOS7.
When I'm trying to send a text message, the modal view appears but there is a strange gap between the "to" field and the list of possible contacts.
After selecting the first contact, the "to" field slides up and disappears and then I see past messages and my new message but with the same gap again.
I'm attaching two images showing the issue:
[image: Selecting contact. Gap is in the red arrow]
[image: After selecting contact]

Here is the code I'm using:

```
if([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText]) {
NSArray *recipents = nil;
NSString *message = @"Let's go";

MFMessageComposeViewController *messageController = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];
messageController.messageComposeDelegate = self;
[messageController setRecipients:recipents];
[messageController setBody:message];
[self presentModalViewController:messageController animated:YES];
}
```

Please tell me if know you know how to fix this issue.
Thanks!

Additional info:
This bug only happens in iOS 7.x not in in iOS 6.x
Also, if I use the MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate to send emails, it works just fine (although they are both implemented by MessageUI.h)...

Comment: Is your app normally landscape?

Comment: I can't replicate this on an iPhone 5. iOS 7.0.4

Comment: `presentModalViewController` is deprecated in iOS 6 as you can see on [Deprecated UIViewController Methods](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html). Could this be the problem..?

Comment: It is strange that I did not get any warning about this but I changed the code to [self presentViewController: messageController animated:YES completion:nil]; and there was no change. Still having the same issue...

Comment: I'm using iPhone 4s and able to replicate with iOS 7.0.2 and 7.0.4

Comment: I am using iphone 4s and iOS 7.0.4 but your code runs fine , just have to use PresentViewController rather than presentModalViewController

Comment: Could it be somehow related to the new iOS 7 uinavigationController? In my uiviewcontroller I'm doing:[self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out.
The issue happens because I have a custom UINavigationController.
In my AppDelegate, I had the following code:

```
UIImage *navBarImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"BarIos7.png"];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:navBarImage forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Once I removed it, everything started working fine.

Comment: Make sure to open a bug report!